# React / Apollo Multiple & dynamic call with useLazyQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, apollo-client

I have page display a list of the same component.
Each component can call a query to display a result regarding its parameters.

### Service

```
const QUERY_EXEUCUTE_QUERY_INDICATOR = gql`
    query executeQueryIndicator($uuid: ID!) {
        executeQueryIndicator(uuid: $uuid) {
            uuid
            messages {
                type
                text
            }
            values
        }
    }
`

export const queryIndicatorExecution = () => {
    const [executeQueryIndicator, {called, loading, data}] = useLazyQuery(
        QUERY_EXEUCUTE_QUERY_INDICATOR,{fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'}
    )

    return {executeQueryIndicator, called, loading, data}
}
```

### Component

```
const {executeQueryIndicator, called, loading, data} = queryIndicatorExecution()
```

I need to call this query as many as I have components displayed (dynamically) in my page

```
 executeQueryIndicator({variables: {uuid1}})
 executeQueryIndicator({variables: {uuid2}})
 executeQueryIndicator({variables: {uuid3}})
...........
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found. I use to separate API (GraphQL) call on service(s) and use service methods in my components

In my service I set a methode using ApolloClient in order to be able to set a Promise on:

MyService.ts

```
const QUERY_QUERY_INDICATOR_RESULT = gql`
    query queryIndicatorResult($uuid: ID!) {
        queryIndicatorResult(uuid: $uuid) {
            uuid
            messages {
                type
                text
            }
            value
        }
    }
`
...

export const queryIndicatorResultPromise = (client: ApolloClient<Object>, indicatorUuid: string) => {
        return client.query({
            query: QUERY_QUERY_INDICATOR_RESULT,
            variables: {uuid: indicatorUuid},
            fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
        })
    }
```

In my component I delclare ApolloClient, services methods, and I set a Promise on service method call:

```
const QueryIndicators = () => {
    const client = useApolloClient()
    ....

    // On method call (or useEffect)
    const handleClick = () => {
      queryIndicatorResultPromise(client, uuidOnProcess).then(result => {
        // Result, set you code on Promise.then
         ... 
        )
   }


return (
      <div>
       .....
      </div>
  )
}
```

export default QueryIndicators